# NSCollectionView dont animate reordering

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I'am updating the item size of my collection items with a slider

```
NSSize size = NSMakeSize(ratio, ratio);
[collectionView setMinItemSize:size];
[collectionView setMaxItemSize:size];
```

**However i don't want the reorder animation to happen (the cells should just appear on their new positions)**

Comment: Where's the code for `setMinItemSize` and `setMaxItemSize`? These are not `UICollectionView` APIs.

Comment: it's an NSCollectionView

Comment: My bad. It was tagged with `UICollectionView`